# django <-> node.js fast communication

Tags: python, django, node.js, zerorpc

I tried `requests` but it seems slow because of the tcp connection takes long (I don't know how to keep the socket open)

I'm now trying `zerorpc` and it has notion of `persistent connection`.
Django <-> node.js communication works fine for the first message but it fails with `Lost remote after 10s heartbeat` error from the second attempt.

I am probably missing something obvious.

```
# following connection step is done in python a module so that it gets called only one time 
import zerorpc

client = zerorpc.Client()
client.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:7015")

def something(...):
   # this gets called for a http request, and we are messaging node.js using the zerorpc client.
   ...
   client.call_rpc(message)
```

Other clients (from command line) can still talk to server and get a response, so I guess it has to do with the above django code.

Answer (score 2):

zerorpc uses gevent for cooperative asynchronous IOs while django handles one request at a time. When django is handling some IOs, zerorpc doesn't get its fair share of CPU time, and cannot handle the heartbeat. Turning off the heartbeat is possible in the zerorpc-python (for this very reason) but is not on zerorpc-node!

One solution is to run django on top of the gevent ioloop, it looks like http://gunicorn.org/ can be of some help.

Comment: thanks for the explanation why! about the solution, I moved on, and will take some time to try it..